# Calling a MaybeNull generic method from another generic method

Tags: c#, generics, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have an extension method like this:

```
[return: MaybeNull]
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
where TKey : notnull
where TValue : notnull {
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out TValue value)) return value;
    else return default!;
}
```

This works fine. Were I to call it expecting a non-null value, the compiler warns me the results could be null, which is exactly what I want.

However, if I have another method that calls `GetValueOrDefault`, and I forget to add the `[return: MaybeNull]`, the compiler won't warn me at all. Here's a convoluted example just to explain my issue:

```
public static TValue SomeOtherMethod<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
where TKey : notnull
where TValue : notnull
    => dictionary.GetValueOrDefault(key); // No warning this could be null

...

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    ["hello"] = "world"
};
string s1 = dictionary.GetValueOrDefault("foo"); // Compiler warning
string s2 = dictionary.SomeOtherMethod("foo"); // No compiler warning
int s2Len = s2.Length; // Visual Studio states "s2 is not null here", even though it absolutely is!
```

I'm pretty new to C# 8.0 nullable reference types, especially involving generics. Is there anything I'm missing to get this to work? Without the compiler warning, it feels like it defeats the purpose of using C# 8.0 nullable types. I'm lulled into a false sense of security that I couldn't possibly miss a NullReferenceException, especially when Visual Studio reassures me "s2 is not null here" even though it absolutely is.

Comment: I think, that the reason of that `TKey` and `TValue` can be reference of value type in your example. And compiler simply doesn't know, whether type itself can be in runtime

Comment: It's true; if I used `where TValue : class` instead, and made the return type `TValue?`, the compiler will warn me fine. But TValue won't always be a class; I sometimes have value types on my IDictionary.

Comment: You can refer to this [document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/), especially to _The `notnull` generic constraint_ and _issue with `T?`_ parts

Comment: You can also have a look at existing threads, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593923/nullable-reference-types-with-generic-return-type) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975211/nullable-reference-types-how-to-specify-t-type-without-constraining-to-class). It seems, that `MaybeNull` is the best option here, and you should use to help the compiler to identify the correct return type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been improved in newer versions of the compiler (still C# 8, just a newer compiler). If you use a newer Visual Studio, you will have a newer compiler.

Here is your example:

https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=

There are two improvements:

1. You don't need to `!` the `default` as the analysis now respects the `MaybeNull` attribute on `GetValueOrDefault`.
2. You now get warning CS8603 (Possible null reference return) where you were previously pointing out that you didn't get a warning but rightly should.

Comment: Upgraded Visual Studio to 16.5.4 and, confirmed, it fixed the issues. Many thanks!