# Tell the caller that a `async Task<T>` method may return null

Tags: c#, generics, async-await, nullable-reference-types

My situation is similar to the one described [Proper nullable annotation for async generic method that may return default(T)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891504/proper-nullable-annotation-for-async-generic-method-that-may-return-defaultt).

However, I'd like to know the proper way to let the caller know that the "return value" might be null.

```
    public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>()
    {
        // sometimes returns default(T)!;
    }
```

If this was not an async method I could use the MaybeNull attribute.

```
    [return: MaybeNull]
    public T Get<T>()
    {
        // sometimes returns default(T)!;
    }
```

If it was not generic I could just use the `?` syntax.

```
    public async Task<string?> GetAsync()
    {
        // sometimes returns default(string)!;
    }
```

Is there a way to let the caller know that it could be null without adding a generic constraint?

EDIT:
To clarify I mean let the compiler know that the value in the task may be null.
I suppose the reverse is also true.
I'm mostly interested in how this is supposed to work with the new C# nullable reference syntax.

I can do something like this just fine

```
    var a = await GetAsync<string?>(); // a is null
    var b = await GetAsync<int?>(); // b is null
    var c = await GetAsync<string>(); // c is null.  Wait string is not supposed to be null and the compiler won't warn you if you use it!
    var d = await GetAsync<int>(); // d is 0
```

EDIT:
I can do something like this just fine

```
    var a = await Get<string?>(); // a is null
    var b = await Get<int?>(); // b is null
    var c = await Get<string>(); // c is null.  
    var d = await Get<int>(); // d is 0
```

The suggestion of [Nullable reference types: How to specify "T?" type without constraining to class or struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975211/nullable-reference-types-how-to-specify-t-type-without-constraining-to-class) is similar, but the Box class can be modified to provide the proper warnings where I cannot change the implementation of Task.

Comment: Add a /// summary tag?

Comment: @itsme86, when I say caller I mean the compiler as applied to the calling code

Comment: You might be able to use the attributes that the compiler uses.

Comment: The [CSharpFunctionalExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CSharpFunctionalExtensions/) package contains a Maybe monad.  
This might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, the attribute the compiler is using is not allowed to be specified in source. You will need IL-level hijinx to get it in there. In other words, you will not be able to trick the compiler.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/30953#issuecomment-619290623

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nullable reference types: How to specify "T?" type without constraining to class or struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975211/nullable-reference-types-how-to-specify-t-type-without-constraining-to-class)

Comment: Looks like you will need to wait for C#9, or write overloads for each struct / class constraint.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 8, you can't express this because you can't apply the `[MaybeNull]` attribute to the type argument to `Task<T>`.

In C# 9, you can just make the return type nullable.

```
public async Task<T?> GetAsync<T>()
{
    // sometimes returns default(T)!;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Here similar topic: [Nullable type as a generic parameter possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209160/nullable-type-as-a-generic-parameter-possible)

The problem here is that we don't know what type `T` is and by that i mean is it class or struct. If it will always be struct than i suggest using `Nullable<T>` or `T?` with constaraint `where T : struct`. But in case when it can be class by definition class can be null because it is reference type.

Only way you can tell caller what might he get if there is no constraint is to use `/// <summary>` as itsme86 mentioned or give method more meaningful name eg. `GetOrDefaultAsync()`

EDIT: 
Referring to Stefan answer it is good solution to use some functional programming tricks and create wrapper for returning type that indicates if returned object has value.

Comment: That's not exactly true because we have the same issue on non-async methods but you can tell the compiler that the result maybe null using attributes.

Comment: The attribute you need to use in this particular case, however, is not allowed to be used in source code. You can declare a copy of the attribute which might've fooled the compiler, but when you try to use it you are told "CS8623: Explicit application of 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute' is not allowed."