# Interface passing int or string as generic type and using in nullable and not nullable properties

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I'm trying to do a Interface for property changes in a product. In some case the values are **int** others the values would by **string**.
The new value is required, but sometimes the field don't have a old value.

Something like this:

```
public interface IChangeSuggestion<TValue> {
    TValue? OldValue { get; set; } //Line with error
    TValue NewValue { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeSuggestionSomeId : IChangeSuggestion<int> {
    public int? OldValue { get; set; }
    public int NewValue { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeSuggestionName : IChangeSuggestion<string> {
    public string OldValue { get; set; }
    public string NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

the code above throw the error:
A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type. Consider adding a 'class', 'struct', or type constraint.

**Edit**

I'm using the interface because a shared approval logic, and the classes are Models for the Entity Framework

To make work in the Entity Framework the follow code do the trick:

```
public interface IChangeSuggestion<TValue> {
    TValue OldValue { get; set; }
    [Required]
    TValue NewValue { get; set; }
    
    int Id { get; set; }
    int ProductId { get; set; }
    bool? Approved { get; set; }
    DateTime? ApprovedOn { get; set; }
    string ApprovedById { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeSuggestionSomeId : IChangeSuggestion<int?> {
    public int? OldValue { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int? NewValue { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public bool? Approved { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ApprovedOn { get; set; }
    public string ApprovedById { get; set; }
}
```

This works because i'm using Entity Framework that run a validate on SaveChanges, but i think that strictly NewValue should be a int not a int?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593923/nullable-reference-types-with-generic-return-type

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure the `TValue` just would be `int`, `bool`, or other value types, you can use `where TValue : struct`. Or `where TValue : class` for just reference types.

```cs
public interface ChangeSuggestion<TValue> where TValue : struct
{
    TValue? OldValue { get; set; }
    TValue NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise, you can only use two interfaces with different names (one for value type, one for reference type). Or use another more complex solution.

Here's my guess.

I assume you know about there's two kind of types including value type (struct) and reference type.
I think what you really want to ask is now that C# support nullable value type, why we can't use `TValue?`, I think that's because, in theory, value type variable which points to the stack can't be null, but sometimes we do need it to be nullable. To achieve this, the **compiler** will make some preprocess during compiling if a value type variable marked as nullable, but a reference type doesn't need this 'preprocess' to be nullable, so we must tell the **compiler** which type the `TValue` is then the **compiler** can decide to do or not do this 'preprocess'.

Comment: The issue is that int is a struct and string is a class, my work around solution is TValue as int? and [Required] attribute on the NewValue...

Comment: @Diógenes Yeah, I forgot about that, then you can only use two interfaces (one for value type, one for reference type) with different names. Or another more complex solution.